# bootstrap form validation is not applying, even bootstrap demo form not working on test-site

Tags: bootstrap-5

i have added both cnd link for bootstrap in boilerplate but form still get submited instead of showing error idk what is going wrong even after copying demo form from bootstrap that form also stop working for some reasong idk why. can someone please explain why ?

boilerPlate -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">  

</head>

<body >
    <%- include('navbar/navbar.ejs')  %>
    <main class="container"> 
        <%- body -%>
    </main>
    <%- include('navbar/footer.ejs') %> 
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

form.ejs

```
<% layout('BaseTemplate') %>

<h1 class="mb-5 offset-5">New product</h1>

<form action="/product" method="post" class="w-50 offset-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
    <label for="name" class="form-lable mb-1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"class="form-control mb-3" required>
    <label for="price" class="form-lable mb-1">Price</label>
    <input type="number" id="price" name="price"class="form-control mb-3" required>
    <label for="description" class="form-lable mb-1">Description</label>
    <input type="text" id="description" name="description"class="form-control mb-3" required>
    <label for="image" class="form-lable mb-1">Image</label>
    <input type="text" id="image" name="image" class="form-control mb-3" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Submit</button>
</form>
```

i want to know why is bootstrap form validation not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have the form attribute `novalidate` on your `<form>` tag. When present, it specifies that the form-data should not be validated when submitted.

Not related to your issue, you also have a typo on your `<label>`s: `class="form-lable"` which sets a `margin-bottom` of `0.5rem`, probably why you added the margin class `mb-1` so I removed it in the fixed form:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="/product" method="post" class="w-50 offset-3 needs-validation">
  <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control mb-3" required>
  <label for="price" class="form-label">Price</label>
  <input type="number" id="price" name="price" class="form-control mb-3" required>
  <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
  <input type="text" id="description" name="description" class="form-control mb-3" required>
  <label for="image" class="form-label">Image</label>
  <input type="text" id="image" name="image" class="form-control mb-3" required>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I found out that I need to add one script separately to activate bootstrap validation